# WooCommerce Loop through product's custom post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, post-meta

So basically I am trying to loop through custom post meta, that I added to the CSV Import Excel File via Custom Header Reference ( e.g meta:Temperatur ). When I output all of the post_meta I see that my added custom meta is added successfully:

```
$postMeta = get_post_meta($productID);
var_dump( $postMeta);
```

This outputs the post meta like this:

[image]

As you see, in line 6 there is my key 'temperatur' that I added.

I tried different variations (see in loop) , and I output the product ID so that I see if i have the right product selected.
Still I can't loop through it with the following code:

```
global $product;
$productID = $product->get_id();

echo '<h2>' . $tab['title'] . '</h2>';
echo $productID;
$attributes = array('Temperatur' , 'Kaeltemittel' , 'Innenfarbe');

foreach ($attributes as $key){
    echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id() , 'Temperatur' , true);
    echo get_post_meta( $productID , $key , true);
}
```

How can I get my custom post_meta that I added via CSV Importer Excel

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: _“When I output all of the post_meta I see that my added custom meta is added successfully.”_ - can you please show what that actually looks like? How do you request it, and what is the actual output.

Comment: @CBroe Of course,  I updated the answer!

Comment: `Temperatur` and `temperatur` are two different things. Array keys are case-sensitive.

Comment: @CBroe You are absolutely right. It worked now. I got confused because I added the meta field via CSV Importer Excel, and named it 'Temperatur' with a capital Letter.  Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to output the keys in their properly cased version as well (so that the output reads `Temparatur: 15C` or something), then you can use `strtolower` to transform them into the proper cases to access the meta value. Or, you could use an array that contains the key name and the label to begin with, `$attributes = array('temperatur' => 'Temperatur', …);`, and then loop over that using the extended foreach syntax. That would have the advantage, that you could also spell `Kältemittel` with the proper German umlaut in the output.

Comment: @CBroe I appreciate your help my friend. I was already coming to terms with the Umlaut problem, but I will take your advice for sure, thank you very much!